# How can i improve this encapsulated javascript code using imutable method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oop

I have this code, but I need to return pure functions instead the mutating functions.

Is it possible? Perhaps using OOP? I don't know how to improve it.

I tried to return the values in each function, but I haven't had success.

```
import { AssetStatusType } from '@domain/interfaces/common'

import {
  BothComponentType,
  ComponentsType,
  GroupFiltersType,
  OperationType,
  OverviewModelType,
  PendenciesOverviewType,
  PendenciesType,
  StructurePendenciesCount,
  StructureStatusCount
} from '../../types'

const updateStatusCount = (
  statusCount: StructureStatusCount,
  status: AssetStatusType
) => {
  statusCount[status] = (statusCount[status] || 0) + 1
}

const updatePendenciesCount = (
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  key: AssetStatusType,
  subKey: OperationType | PendenciesOverviewType
) => {
  pendenciesCount[key] = pendenciesCount[key] ?? {}
  pendenciesCount[key][subKey] = (pendenciesCount[key]?.[subKey] || 0) + 1
}

const processOverviewPendencies = (
  pendencies: PendenciesType[] | null | undefined,
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  countedIds: Set<string>,
  id: string
) => {
  if (pendencies?.length) {
    for (const { state, pendencyType } of pendencies) {
      const uniqueId = `${state}-${pendencyType}-${id}`
      if (!countedIds.has(uniqueId)) {
        updatePendenciesCount(pendenciesCount, state, pendencyType)
        countedIds.add(uniqueId)
        return {state, pendencyType}
      }
    }
  }
}

const processOverviewComponents = (
  components: ComponentsType[],
  isGroupByTree: boolean,
  statusCount: StructureStatusCount,
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  countedIds: Set<string>,
  id: string,
  type: BothComponentType
) => {
  for (const { pendencies, status, operationType } of components) {
    if (isGroupByTree && type === 'location') {
      updateStatusCount(statusCount, status)

      if (operationType) {
        updatePendenciesCount(pendenciesCount, status, operationType)
      }
    }
    processOverviewPendencies(pendencies, pendenciesCount, countedIds, id)
  }
}

const processOverviewData = (
  data: OverviewModelType[],
  groupBy: GroupFiltersType,
  statusCount: StructureStatusCount,
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  countedIds: Set<string>
) => {
  const isGroupByTree = groupBy === 'tree'
  const isGroupByAsset = groupBy === 'asset'

  for (const { id, status, components, operationType, type } of data) {
    if (isGroupByAsset || type === 'asset') {
      updateStatusCount(statusCount, status)
      if (operationType) {
        updatePendenciesCount(pendenciesCount, status, operationType)
      }
    }

    processOverviewComponents(
      components,
      isGroupByTree,
      statusCount,
      pendenciesCount,
      countedIds,
      id,
      type
    )
  }
}

export const calculateOverviewCounts = (
  data: OverviewModelType[],
  groupBy: GroupFiltersType
) => {
  const statusCount: StructureStatusCount = {} as StructureStatusCount
  const pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount =
    {} as StructurePendenciesCount

  const countedIds = new Set<string>()

  const {} = processOverviewData(data, groupBy, statusCount, pendenciesCount, countedIds)

  // statusCount[status] = (statusCount[status] || 0) + 1

  return { ...statusCount, pendencies: pendenciesCount }
}
```

Is there a cleaner and more elegant way to do this? I need to return an object like this:

```
// calculateOverviewCounts return this

{
    pendencies: StructurePendenciesCount;
    working: number;
    inAlert: number;
    warning: number;
    stopped: number;
    off: number;
}
```

StructurePendenciesCount is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emvj8.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Wesley! This question will likely get closed since it will lead to opinion based answers. Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit. But if you have _specific_ questions about this code, you can [edit] the question to be about that. For example you could say "the following lines have duplicated logic. How can I reduce that duplication?". But general requests for "improvement" are not on topic here. Here you can ask _specific_ questions, and get un-opinionated answer to those questions.

Comment: Hi, Alex. I don't know. I'm so sorry